# load spinner dynamically into getview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, getview

i have a class fragmentProducts.java , which i load my products in a listview.

into my xml layout , i have texts and two spinners , one for size and one for colour. everything is ok for the texts , they are shown. I have a problem with the spinners because i think that i should add an **arrayAdapter** into the **GetView**.
**i get fatal exception: E/AndroidRuntime(29244): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a005b type #0x12 is not valid at android.content.res.loadXMLResourceParser(Resources.java:2407)...**

my GetView code with the ViewHelper class ,is this:

```
   `private class ViewHolder {
            TextView prName;
            TextView prDescription;
            TextView prfprice;
            ImageView prImage;
            //spinners
            Spinner PrVariants;     
            Spinner PrOptions;

            int ProdPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;

            View view = convertView;
            final ProductsData info = getItem(position);

            if (view == null) {
                // Product row
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.productslistitem_layout, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                assert view != null;
                viewHolder.prName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                viewHolder.prDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_description);
                viewHolder.prfprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_fprice);
                viewHolder.prImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_image);

                **//here i try to put test values on the spinner//**
                viewHolder.PrVariants = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spOptions1);
                String[] names = {"test1","test2","test3"};

                var1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.id.spOptions1,names);
                var1Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                viewHolder.PrVariants.setAdapter(var1Adapter);

                viewHolder.prfprice.setText("120.00" + "€");
                viewHolder.prName.setText(info.getPrName());
                viewHolder.prDescription.setText(info.getPrComments());

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            return view;
        }`
```

Does anyone understand the error message? should i not use arrayadapter into the GetView function?

Answer (score 0):

> Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a005b type #0x12

Because `ArrayAdapter` take **Layout id** instead of **View id** as second parameter.

```
var1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                       <Layout_Id_In_Which_Spinner_Added>,names);
```

Comment: i have the spinner into productslistitem_layout.xml, with all the other components.

Comment: @user3520356 : then pass `R.layout.productslistitem_layout` in ArrayAdapter as second parameter

Answer (score 0):

thank you,unfortunatelly i could not make it work with your answer:
`var1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.id.layoutspOptions1,names)`.
 //layoutspOptions1 is the linearLayout id that i have the spinner in.

Although it worked by changing the arrayAdapter to:

`var1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,names);

var1Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

So, we dont use the R.id.spinnerId as a second parameter of the ArrayAdapter but a default layout : android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item